# How to automatically set post title according to custom meta fields

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to automatically set my post title according to custom meta fields for example my custom meta fields have a Name of user I want the title of the post to be the Name of User hope you can help me with this

Comment: Have you tried any solutions? If yes please give the code sample here. So we can check and assist you.

Comment: Your question is nonsensical.   It's easy to use JavaScript to create the page title.  Create the string you want to use as the title (e.g. $title). Give the <title> an id:  `title id="title">`.  The in the JS add: document.getElementById('title') = $title  Don't use meta tags.  Just have your PHP code add the above code into the `<script>`

Answer (score 2):

You can use WordPress' "save_post" hook to change the post title according to post meta whenever a post is saved. Lets say you fave a post meta field called "name_of_user" and you want to change the post title accordingly

```
add_action('save_post', 'wpse_update_post_title');

function wpse_update_post_title($post_id) {
// If this is just a revision, don't update the title yet.
if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {
    return;
}

// unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
remove_action('save_post', 'wpse_update_post_title');

$user_name = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'name_of_user', true );
// Check if the meta for given key exists and then update the title 
if($user_name) {
    $slug = str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($user_name))
    $post_update = array(
        'ID'         => $post_id,
        'post_title' => $user_name,
        'post_name' => $slug // This swill update the url slug of the post too`enter code here`
    );

    wp_update_post( $post_update );
}

// re-hook this function
add_action('save_post', 'wpse_update_post_title');
}
```

The above code should go into your theme's functions.php file